# Javascript profiler not working with external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**In Google Chrome I am using the Chrome Developer Tools feature to test my javascript** performance via the profiler, but it seems that the profiler doesn't work well with external `.js` files.

"external `.js` file" stands for a file linked at the bottom of the page, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myfile.js"></script>
```

I want to analyse peace by peace of my code, so I'm isolating the desired part with the `console.profile();` and `console.profileEnd();` methods, as so:

```
console.profile();
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myDiv').fadeIn();
});
console.profileEnd();
```

But this returns an `(anonymous function)` with no results.

What is wrong and why does it return this nonsense?

Comment: Could define 'external' javascript files?

Comment: @NickTomlin just edited the question ;)

Comment: Have you tried to move the profilers inside the document ready handler? I don't think there's something going on before/after, but just within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **MelanciaUK** in the comments:

> Have you tried to move the profilers inside the document ready
>   handler? I don't think there's something going on before/after, but
>   just within.

This solves the problem! ;)